# iPhone no longer plays music/audiobook/podcast when I press the headphone button

Tags: ios, podcasts.app, music.app

Since I replaced my 3GS with a 4S (and iOS 7) stopping and restarting music/audiobooks/podcasts doesn't work any more.

Basically, instead of pressing the button on the headphone microphone once to continue playing what I was listening to earlier, I now have to log into the phone, select one of two audio players and there press play to continue playing.

Have I configured something wrong or did I just lose that feature?

Comment: My iPhone 4 recently quit responding to the earbud button when playing music.  I replaced with another newer set of earbuds, and it was OK.  So I assumed that button had gone bad, and happening just when I switched to iOS7 was just a coincidence.

Comment: I would determine if it is hardware problem or software problem by enabling Control Center in the lock screen, and then using that to play the music after it has been paused. I think, if it was on iOS issue, that the same problem would occur there.

Comment: I use the same headphones with my laptop. The button works.